# How to add values to a column between 2 set values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas df that looks like this:

```
x         y
1         b
2         NaN
3         aStart
4         aStart
5         NaN
6         NaN
7         NaN
8         NaN
9         aEnd  
10        c
11        aStart
12        NaN
13        aEnd
```

Whenever there is a gap in between `aStart` and `aStop`, I want to fill those rows in the `y` column with `a`. I only want to fill in the rows in between the `aStart` and `aStop` occurrences. I then want to replace the initial `aStart` and `aStop` values with np.nan `NaN` values. It should look like this:

```
x         y
1         b
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
5         a
6         a
7         a
8         a
9         NaN  
10        c
11        NaN
12        a
13        NaN
```

## Edit

How do I complete this task if there are other items in `df.y` that I want to ignore? For example, if `b` and `c` are present in `df.y`, how do I ignore those, but keep the original process?

Comment: @rej you miss the whole point of numpy/ pandas with enhanced performance with vectorized operations... go look in google about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> pd.Series('a', index=df.index).where(df['y'].ffill().eq('aStart') & df['y'].bfill().eq('aEnd'))
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4       a
5       a
6       a
7       a
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    NaN
11      a
12    NaN
dtype: object
```

Here’s what this does:

1. put `'a'` everywhere
2. with `.where()`, keep only values where the series is `True`
3. which is where:

   - the last non-NA value (with `.ffill()`) is `aStart`, and
   - the next non-NA value (with `.bfill()`) is `aEnd`

If there are other elements in `df['y']`, you can drop them beforehand:

```
>>> start_stop = df['y'].where(df['y'].isin({'aStart', 'aEnd'}))
>>> pd.Series('a', index=df.index).where(start_stop.ffill().eq('aStart') & start_stop.bfill().eq('aEnd'))
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4       a
5       a
6       a
7       a
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    NaN
11      a
12    NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: That was brilliant, thank you! I forgot to ask in my OP, what if there are other values in df.y that I want to keep and ignore? See edits in the post. I will still accept this answer as it answered my original question regardless. Thank you!

Comment: Just tweak the `df['y']` to remove those  @connor449. I’ve added that in too.

Comment: can’t you just find a way?